# Collapsibles on the same line Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap for my project, and I am trying to have collabsibles on the same line. They appear on the same line, but if I dropdown the first collapsible, the other collapsible moves down into the first collapsible.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR4JR.png)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6Nn2.png)

I currently have two collapsibles written like so:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Nerve Cuffs</h2>
      <hr>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#2-Channel">2-Channel Nerve Cuffs <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></button>
      <div id="2-Channel" class="collapse">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <h4>NC-630-2</h4>
        </div>

      </div>
      <h5><span class="badge badge-secondary">2-Channel</span></h5>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#1">Specifications <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></button>
      <div id="1" class="collapse">
      <p>Electrode Length: 0.630mm <br>
         Electrode Width: 0.150m <br>
         Electrode Area: 0.095 mm<sup>2</sup> <br>
         Electrode Sites: 2 <br>
         Electrode Spacing: 1.000m 
        </p>
      <p>Device Length: 5.000m <br>
         Device Width: 2.00mm <br>
         Device Thickness: 30 ± 5 μm   
        </p>
      <p>
        Standard Electrode Material: TiN <br>
        Connector Options: Bare wires, Plastics One, Omnetics  
        </p>    
        </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <h4>NC-1210-2</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h5><span class="badge badge-secondary">2-Channel</span></h5>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#2">Specifications <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></button>
      <div id="2" class="collapse">
       <p>Electrode Length: 1.210mm <br>
         Electrode Width: 0.150m <br>
         Electrode Area: 0.182 mm<sup>2</sup> <br>
         Electrode Sites: 2 <br>
         Electrode Spacing: 1.000m 
        </p>
      <p>Device Length: 10.000m <br>
         Device Width: 2.00mm <br>
         Device Thickness: 30 ± 5 μm   
        </p>
      <p>
        Standard Electrode Material: TiN <br>
        Connector Options: Bare wires, Plastics One, Omnetics  
        </p>
        </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <h4>NC-1620-2</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h5><span class="badge badge-secondary">2-Channel</span></h5>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#3">Specifications <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></button>
      <div id="3" class="collapse">
       <p>Electrode Length: 1.620mm <br>
         Electrode Width: 0.150m <br>
         Electrode Area: 0.243 mm<sup>2</sup> <br>
         Electrode Sites: 2 <br>
         Electrode Spacing: 1.000m 
        </p>
      <p>Device Length: 10.000m <br>
         Device Width: 2.00mm <br>
         Device Thickness: 30 ± 5 μm   
        </p>
      <p>
        Standard Electrode Material: TiN <br>
        Connector Options: Bare wires, Plastics One, Omnetics  
        </p>
        </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <h4>NC-2600-2</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
        <h5><span class="badge badge-secondary">2-Channel</span></h5>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#4">Specifications <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></button>
      <div id="4" class="collapse">
       <p>Electrode Length: 2.600mm <br>
         Electrode Width: 0.150m <br>
         Electrode Area: 0.390 mm<sup>2</sup> <br>
         Electrode Sites: 2 <br>
         Electrode Spacing: 1.000m 
        </p>
      <p>Device Length: 10.000m <br>
         Device Width: 2.00mm <br>
         Device Thickness: 30 ± 5 μm   
        </p>
      <p>Standard Electrode Material: TiN <br>
        Connector Options: Bare wires, Plastics One, Omnetics  
        </p>
      </div>
      </div>        
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#4-Channel">4-Channel Nerve Cuffs <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></button>
      <div id="4-Channel" class="collapse">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <h4>NC-1210-4</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h5><span class="badge badge-secondary">4-Channel</span></h5>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#5">Specifications <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></button>
      <div id="5" class="collapse">
       <p>Electrode Length: 1.210mm <br>
         Electrode Width: 0.150m <br>
         Electrode Area: 0.182 mm<sup>2</sup> <br>
         Electrode Sites: 4 <br>
         Electrode Spacing: 1.000m 
        </p>
      <p>Device Length: 10.000m <br>
         Device Width: 4.00mm <br>
         Device Thickness: 30 ± 5 μm   
        </p>
      <p>Standard Electrode Material: TiN <br>
        Connector Options: Bare wires, Plastics One, Omnetics  
        </p>
        </div>


     </div>
      </div>              
    </div>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: can you post the entire navbar code?

Comment: I updated the post. Is this what you needed?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Nerve Cuffs</h2>
      <hr>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#2-Channel">2-Channel Nerve Cuffs <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#4-Channel">4-Channel Nerve Cuffs <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></button>
                </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
                        <div id="2-Channel" class="collapse">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <h4>NC-630-2</h4>
        </div>

      </div>
      <h5><span class="badge badge-secondary">2-Channel</span></h5>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#1">Specifications <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></button>
      <div id="1" class="collapse">
      <p>Electrode Length: 0.630mm <br>
         Electrode Width: 0.150m <br>
         Electrode Area: 0.095 mm<sup>2</sup> <br>
         Electrode Sites: 2 <br>
         Electrode Spacing: 1.000m 
        </p>
      <p>Device Length: 5.000m <br>
         Device Width: 2.00mm <br>
         Device Thickness: 30 ± 5 μm   
        </p>
      <p>
        Standard Electrode Material: TiN <br>
        Connector Options: Bare wires, Plastics One, Omnetics  
        </p>    
        </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <h4>NC-1210-2</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h5><span class="badge badge-secondary">2-Channel</span></h5>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#2">Specifications <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></button>
      <div id="2" class="collapse">
       <p>Electrode Length: 1.210mm <br>
         Electrode Width: 0.150m <br>
         Electrode Area: 0.182 mm<sup>2</sup> <br>
         Electrode Sites: 2 <br>
         Electrode Spacing: 1.000m 
        </p>
      <p>Device Length: 10.000m <br>
         Device Width: 2.00mm <br>
         Device Thickness: 30 ± 5 μm   
        </p>
      <p>
        Standard Electrode Material: TiN <br>
        Connector Options: Bare wires, Plastics One, Omnetics  
        </p>
        </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <h4>NC-1620-2</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h5><span class="badge badge-secondary">2-Channel</span></h5>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#3">Specifications <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></button>
      <div id="3" class="collapse">
       <p>Electrode Length: 1.620mm <br>
         Electrode Width: 0.150m <br>
         Electrode Area: 0.243 mm<sup>2</sup> <br>
         Electrode Sites: 2 <br>
         Electrode Spacing: 1.000m 
        </p>
      <p>Device Length: 10.000m <br>
         Device Width: 2.00mm <br>
         Device Thickness: 30 ± 5 μm   
        </p>
      <p>
        Standard Electrode Material: TiN <br>
        Connector Options: Bare wires, Plastics One, Omnetics  
        </p>
        </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <h4>NC-2600-2</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
        <h5><span class="badge badge-secondary">2-Channel</span></h5>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#4">Specifications <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></button>
      <div id="4" class="collapse">
       <p>Electrode Length: 2.600mm <br>
         Electrode Width: 0.150m <br>
         Electrode Area: 0.390 mm<sup>2</sup> <br>
         Electrode Sites: 2 <br>
         Electrode Spacing: 1.000m 
        </p>
      <p>Device Length: 10.000m <br>
         Device Width: 2.00mm <br>
         Device Thickness: 30 ± 5 μm   
        </p>
      <p>Standard Electrode Material: TiN <br>
        Connector Options: Bare wires, Plastics One, Omnetics  
        </p>
      </div>
      </div>        
            </div>
     <div class="col">
                       <div id="4-Channel" class="collapse">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <h4>NC-1210-4</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h5><span class="badge badge-secondary">4-Channel</span></h5>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#5">Specifications <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></button>
      <div id="5" class="collapse">
       <p>Electrode Length: 1.210mm <br>
         Electrode Width: 0.150m <br>
         Electrode Area: 0.182 mm<sup>2</sup> <br>
         Electrode Sites: 4 <br>
         Electrode Spacing: 1.000m 
        </p>
      <p>Device Length: 10.000m <br>
         Device Width: 4.00mm <br>
         Device Thickness: 30 ± 5 μm   
        </p>
      <p>Standard Electrode Material: TiN <br>
        Connector Options: Bare wires, Plastics One, Omnetics  
        </p>
        </div>


     </div>
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

using bootstrap col will solve your problem. Place content of each button in a row with col.